# ID does not reference a View inside this Activity when click on Button or ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and i now i'm getting an error which says "ID does not reference a View inside this Activity", i found nothing and i tried to change the activity name to "package name.activityName" instead of "MainActivity" but still there is not solution when i click on the button or on ImageView the application crash.

And here is the Error which i am facing

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zcorp.daily_budget, PID: 18367
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zcorp.daily_budget/com.zcorp.daily_budget.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1700)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:867)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:368)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.zcorp.daily_budget.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7145)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2878)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1700) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:867)
```

I don't understand what is the problem here. thanks.

This is my Login_activity where i want to move to MainActivity

```
package com.zcorp.daily_budget;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.se.omapi.Session;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;


public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Button btn_login;
    private TextView nav_text;
    private ImageView image_skip;
    private TextView signUp;
    private TextInputEditText editTxtUserId, editTxtUserPass;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_);


        btn_login=findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        nav_text = findViewById(R.id.nav_text);
        image_skip =  findViewById(R.id.image_skip_login);
        signUp = findViewById(R.id.txt_sign_up);
        editTxtUserId =  findViewById(R.id.edittxt_userid);
        editTxtUserPass = findViewById(R.id.edittxt_pass);


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        image_skip.setOnClickListener(this);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(this);


//        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//                                startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
//            }
//        });
//
//        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this, SignUp_Activity.class));
//            }
//        });
//
//
//        image_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
//            }
//        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_login:
                startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.image_skip_login:
                Intent i =  new Intent(Login_Activity.this, com.zcorp.daily_budget.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the xml Layout file for the LoginActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login_Activity"
    android:background="@color/White">

   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_bottom"
       android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp">



           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/skip_image"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               android:paddingRight="10dp"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               android:paddingTop="5dp"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:id="@+id/image_skip_login"/>


           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="100dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
               android:src="@drawable/daily_bugget_app_round_logo"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="Welcome Back"
               android:textColor="@color/Black"
               android:textSize="30sp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
               android:text="Sign in to continue"
               android:textColor="@color/lblue"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.431"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_bold"
               android:text="E-mail"
               android:textColor="@color/Black"
               android:textSize="22sp"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/edittxt_userid"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
               android:foregroundTint="@color/Black"
               android:backgroundTint="@color/Black"
               android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
               android:hint="Email id or user name"
               android:imeOptions="actionNext"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:text=""
               android:textSize="15sp"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_bold"
               android:text="Password"
               android:textColor="@color/Black"
               android:textSize="22sp"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/edittxt_pass"
               android:layout_width="350dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/starndard_margin"
               android:layout_marginTop="421dp"
               android:hint="•••••••••••••••"
               android:text=""
               android:textColor="@color/Black"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/eye_icon_shpass"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
               android:src="@drawable/show_hide_password"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_pass"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="465dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_light"
               android:text="Forgot Password"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
               android:id="@+id/btn_login"
               android:layout_width="250dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="524dp"
               android:backgroundTint="@color/Black"
               android:text="Login"
               android:textAllCaps="false"
               android:textColor="@color/White"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:rippleColor="@color/White"
               app:shapeAppearance="@style/btn_theme"
               app:strokeColor="@color/lblue"
               app:strokeWidth="2dp" />



       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
            android:text="New User ?"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/lblue"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zcorp.daily_budget">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/daily_bugget_app_round_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/daily_bugget_app_round_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SignUp_Activity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppFullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.zcorp.daily_budget.Login_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.zcorp.daily_budget.MainActivity"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the MainActivity

```
package com.zcorp.daily_budget;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    private TextView tv_title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_app);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tv_title=toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_title.setText("Home");



        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send,R.id.nav_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//        return true;
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

So plz if anyone has any solution tell me, i am stuck in this spot.

Comment: Why you are using 2 clicklistener ?

Comment: Cause there are two components one is the Login_Button and another is the Clickable ImageView which is placed at the top right corner in layout, so when user don't want to login or signup he or she can Skip this process so that's why i have to use two different layout for the each components in switch statement.

Comment: I am asking about image_skip .

Comment: Then what should i use for the ImageView

Comment: Use one Clicklistener

Comment: Sorry but i can't understanding the concept of only using one Clicklistener, i am requesting you if you have time to do me a favor then that will be great help for me, just tell me how to fix it and also tell me the method or syntax to fix this, plzzz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210854/discussion-between-akki-jangir-and-muntasir-aonik).

Comment: Just share your error code it will be help ful to debug from the error line it seems you are trying to refer to a xml view which doesn't belong to that activity

Comment: I just added the error in the question for you if you can find any solution let me know